# How to remove the Supervisor BIOS password for an IBM ThinkPad r50e

Tags: bios, passwords, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad r50e 1834 that a friend gave me because it has no hdd, the screen is broken (only the top left is visible) and it has a supervisor password, so it stops booting at a lock symbol waiting for a password. 
I tried following Arpan Dubey's method from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/393922/how-to-remove-the-supervisor-bios-password-for-an-ibm-thinkpad/1407197#1407197) but it doesn't work for me. The problem seems to be the CMOS battery that is shot, so it always boots with a "0271: Check date and time settings" error, followed by the lock symbol. I tried pressing F1 repeatedly but the lock symbol doesn't allow me to go into the BIOS, if pressing Return it simply shows up to 3 xxx then a stop sign with a hand. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Did you ask your friend for the password?

Comment: He doesn't remember it, it's been in his attic for years now. The dead CMOS battery might be the reason why Arpan's steps to enter the "read only" BIOS are not working...

Comment: resetting cmos does not work anymore for modern laptops, the password is stored on a separate chip that is technically much harder to erase.....https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=VzNsXICpK8_MjgS3sa6ACw&q=bios+password+reset+ThinkPad+r50e&btnK=Google+Search&oq=bios+password+reset+ThinkPad+r50e&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.1682.1682..4127...0.0..0.79.79.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....0.dLRM5trClaU

Comment: I think you missed the point. I know resetting the CMOS doesn't clear the password, I even mentioned that the CMOS battery is dead. Arpan's solution/video that I linked in the question has a workaround, the problem seems to be that the CMOS error message I get interferes with his steps, and I can even get to the "read only" BIOS he shows in the video. I'll try to find a compatible CMOS battery but I seriously doubt it will remove the date/time error since I would have to enter the BIOS and set the date/time there first...

Comment: You dont need a cmos battery if you have it plugged in, all the battery does is retain bios settings, you should be able to enter the bios without a cmos battery. If there is a bios password set then you will have to clear it before you can do anything, the video shows how to do that.